# How to merge two list into one list in scala

Tags: scala, list

I have two type of list that contain as follow.

```
List(50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 51, 51, 51)
```

and

```
List(176482, 176481, 176485, 176479, 176478, 176477, 176483, 176480)
```

By using these two list I want to create new list is should contain as follow

```
List(50176482, 50176481, 50176485, 50176479, 50176478, 51176477, 51176483, 51176480)
```

Can any one help on this?

Comment: Is the length of both list always equal?

Comment: yes, length always equal of both list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scala> (List(50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 51, 51, 51) zip List(176482, 176481, 176485, 176479, 176478, 176477, 176483, 176480)).map(x => (x._1.toString + x._2.toString).toInt)
res0: List[Int] = List(50176482, 50176481, 50176485, 50176479, 50176478, 51176477, 51176483, 51176480)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a combination of [zip](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html#zip) and [yield](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) to achieve the results :

```
var myList1 = List(50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 51, 51, 51);
var myList2 = List(176482, 176481, 176485, 176479, 176478, 176477, 176483, 176480);

var finalList = for ( (l1, l2) <- (myList1 zip myList2)) yield (l1.toString + l2.toString).toInt;
```